# How do I reinstall the sound icon / sound menu?

Tags: sound, indicator-sound

I was trying to fix a problem a long time ago with my sound by removing alsa/puleaudio and reinstalling things that I didn't understand.

Now my sound is messed up. The volume keys on my keyboard don't work, and I don't get the same sound indicator menu as I used to that had rhythmbox etc in it.

Also, this happens

```
gnome-volume-control-applet: command not found
```

I'm very sure this is just a matter of re apt-getting some packages and maybe removing, but I don't know which.

The sound itself does play.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to reinstall `indicator-sound`, then log out and back in:

[image: Install via the software center]

or `sudo apt-get install indicator-sound` via the command line.